# Adjust alpha of UIColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, alpha, uicolor

I set a `UIColor` using rgb to a background of a `UILabel`. I'm trying to adjust the `alpha` only. How can I modify the alpha of an existing rgb `UIColor`?

**Edit**

Basically I have `UILabels` that have a set `UIColor` (using rgb), and I won't know what color the `UILabels` are. At a certain point, I will have to change the `labels` alpha`. How can I just change the labels color alpha?

Comment: Of a predefined `UIColor`? For a label you could use the `.alpha` property.

Comment: Thanks for the response!. I have a predefined UIColor. I don't want to set the labels alpha, but the colors alpha

Answer (score 208):

`colorWithAlphaComponent:` did the trick.

So what I had to do was:

```
self.mylabel.backgroundColor = [self.myLabel.backgroundColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];
```

Comment: is there any difference between this approach and say this?
`UIColor(red:0.07, green:0.44, blue:0.54, alpha:0.4)`

Comment: @Changerrs : there can be cases when we need to apply alpha to a existing color. ie existing colors cant not be modified. Hence for such cases we already have a color value, but then need to apply alpha to it hence colorWithAlphaComponent comes handy for such case.

Answer (score 106):

**Swift 3+**

```
yourUIView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
```

**Swift 2**

```
yourUIView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.75)
```

Answer (score 15):

If you have custom colors defined, you can do this as well:

```
view.backgroundColor = [[MyClass someColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.25];
```

Answer (score 11):

Version **Swift (5.4)**

```
UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Answer (score 10):

why not using `label.alpha = 0.5` ? to adjust your label's alpha?

update: if you want to adjust alpha from a old color, here is an example:

```
UIColor uicolor = [UIColor greenColor];
CGColorRef color = [uicolor CGColor];

int numComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color);

UIColor newColor;
if (numComponents == 4)
{
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color);
    CGFloat red = components[0];
    CGFloat green = components[1];
    CGFloat blue = components[2];
    newColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: red green: green blue: blue alpha: YOURNEWALPHA];

}
```

Comment: I don't want to set the labels alpha, I want to set the labels color alpha

Comment: Where's the difference?

Comment: If I set the alpha of the whole label, then the text will also become lighter because I'm setting the background color of the label

Comment: @Eric Do you means change color's alpha from an existing UIColor?

Answer (score 6):

The shortest possible code (**Swift 5**):

```
view.backgroundColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set alpha in below code -

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0/255.0 green:191.0/255.0 blue:231.0 /255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

Comment: I have that code, but I want to modify the alpha only

Comment: you want to set background color of UIlabel and want to change alpha of UILabel right ? Please use above code

Comment: [UIColor colorWithRed:200.0/255 green:191.0/255 blue:231.0/255 alpha:1.0] modify like that

Comment: Yes Right , sorry by mistake